(Auto)-linebreaking a long formula in align environment or with breqn package
I am having problems with writing some equivalences. I tried align* (originally eqnarray*)
        \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathabx,bm}  
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\newcommand{\lamb}[2]{\lambda {#1}^{#2}. }
\newcommand{\bint}{\textbf{int} }
\newcommand{\eqT}{=_\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\eqI}{=_{\bm{i}}}
\begin{document}     
    \begin{align*} 
        (\phi\vee \phi\rightarrow\phi)^D&\equiv  
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            \left[ \exists p^\bint \exists x \exists x' \forall y \forall y' \{(p\eqI \bm{0} \phi_D[x,y])\vee (p\eqI \bm{s}(\bm{0}) \phi_D[x',y'])\}\right.\\   {}  &\left.\rightarrow \exists x'' \forall y'' \phi_D[x'',y'']\right]^D 
        \end{aligned} \\
        {}&\equiv \exists Y \exists Y'\exists X'' \forall p^\bint \forall x \forall x'   \{[(p\eqI \bm{0} \phi_D[x,y])\vee (p\eqI \bm{s}(\bm{0}) \phi_D[x',y'])]\rightarrow  \phi_D[X''pxx'',y'']\}   \\
        {}&\equiv \exists x \forall y \phi_{D}[x',y'] \phi_{D}[x,y] \rightarrow \exists p^{\bint}\exists x' \exists z \forall y' \forall w ((p\eqI \bm{0} \wedge \phi_{D}[x',y'])\vee (p \eqI \bm{0} \wedge \psi_{D}[z,w]))\\
        .....&\equiv \exists Y \exists P \exists X' \exists Z \forall x \forall y' \forall w\{[\phi_{D}[x,Yxy'w]]\rightarrow ((Px\eqI \bm{0} \wedge \phi_{D}[Xx',y'])\vee Px\eqI\bm{0}\bm{s}(\bm{0} \wedge \psi_{D}[Zx,w]))\}                
    \end{align*}
\end{document}

but it doesn't create a nice result (half of the second line disappears out of the page), even if I move the linebreak to the left. I can't really move it to the right.
I tried breqn package too, but it gives to many errors (almost all are related to bm package and they don't appear without breqn) with the other packages. I read in the documentation that it needs "juggling" but I didn't find a good sequence.
I have even bigger formulas  to write (maybe more than 3 lines needed) so, if possible, I prefer automatic linebreak, because they are quite a few and align environment doesn't seem to be easy for breaking a formula.
Do you have any suggestions or a way to generally handle these situations? I searched many posts and tried the solutions but didn't have any luck till now. An example with the formula in the MWE would help me.
Edit: I forgot to mention that I have to add other formulas in the align environment, so I have added some formulae. I have also tried split environment.

Please check your MWE: I get a couple of undefined control sequneces

I added the missing code.

In general getting automatic linebreaking in display math to work is very hard. And for most people just not worth it. It is better to learn how to use the various envs in amsmath and learn how to manually break equations. And yes sometimes you willneed to rewrite your math as it cannot be broken. Even breqn cannot handle all cases.

I often mostly use chapter 3 in https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf as a guide.

I see no reason for align*, unless you have other equations in the same display.
If there's just one, multline* does the job.
Otherwise, use align and aligned the right way.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathabx,bm}  
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\newcommand{\lamb}[2]{\lambda {#1}^{#2}. }
%\newcommand{\produc}[2]{\langle {#1},{#2}\rangle }
\newcommand{\bint}{\mathbf{int}} % NOT \textbf
%\newcommand{\rightarT}{\rightarrow_{\mathcal{T}}}
%\newcommand{\tworightarT}{\twoheadrightarrow_{\mathcal{T}}}
\newcommand{\eqT}{=_{\mathcal{T}}}
\newcommand{\eqI}{=_{\bm{i}}}

\begin{document}     

\section{Single equation and \texttt{multline}}

\begin{multline*}
(\phi\vee \phi\rightarrow\phi)^D \equiv
\bigl[
  \exists p^\bint \exists x \exists x'
  \forall y \forall y'
  \{(p\eqI \bm{0} \phi_D[x,y])\vee (p\eqI \bm{s}(\bm{0}) \phi_D[x',y'])\}
\\
  \rightarrow \exists x'' \forall y'' \phi_D[x'',y'']
\bigr]^D
\end{multline*}

\section{Multiple equations and \texttt{aligned}}

\begin{align*}
(\phi\vee \phi\rightarrow\phi)^D
&\equiv
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[
    \exists p^\bint \exists x \exists x'
    \forall y \forall y'
    \{(p\eqI \bm{0} \phi_D[x,y])\vee (p\eqI \bm{s}(\bm{0}) \phi_D[x',y'])\}
  \\
    \rightarrow \exists x'' \forall y'' \phi_D[x'',y'']
  \bigr]^D
\end{aligned}
\\
&\equiv \dots
\\
&\equiv \dots
\end{align*}

\end{document}


A few notes:

_\mathcal{T} should be _{\mathcal{T}}; the fact the former seems to work doesn't guarantee it will forever;
\mathbf{int} is the correct specification, as \textbf might choose bold italic if the context is italic;
I see no reason for \left and \right.


Thank you for the notes. I fixed them. There were actually other formulas to be put in the next lines of align, but didn't mention them, as I thought that one was enough. I added one in the post.

Could you please add suggestions for the MWE as it is now edited, but keep also the answer for one equation so that I can accept your answer?

@ΝικολέταΣεβαστού Modified as requested
